# Is it allowed to customize the required tag-wiki-excerpts and tag-wiki?

Tags: support, internationalization, required-tags, translations, spanish-stackoverflow

I recently asked a question regarding required-tags because the tag-wiki-excerpt and tag-wiki were not clear enough for me before posting the question. Now I think that I understand the purpose of each one.

Since my mother tongue is not English, before re-reading the tag-wikis I would like to know if tag-wikis for required-tags on international sites like [es.so] should be a direct translation the corresponding tag of a specific site in English, like [so] or [meta].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless the international site has a specific rule requiring tag wikis to be direct translations (which they probably don't), you're free to make a suitable suggestion.

In fact, if you were to directly translate something from Stack Overflow (in English) to another Stack Overflow language, I would expect to see attribution in the form of a link to the place you 'copied' it from.

Comment: I usually include attribution in the form of a link, but I'm not sure that the OP and other contributors do the same on the posts that I contribute.